# Datetimepicker not changing date time onSelect

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

**The problem:**

I have two datetimepicker elements utilizing [trent richardson's datetimepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

The first element selects a start date/time and the second selects an end date/time.
When a date/time is changed i want to check that the start event is still before the end event. If not: the datetimepicker should revert to it's previous value.

**What i've tried**

```
$("selector").datetimepicker(function(){
    //other init values.
    onSelect: function(){
         var start = $("#startStamp").val();
         var stop = $("#stopStamp").val();
         if(calculateTimeDiff(start, stop) <= 0){
             alert("Start time may not exceed end time");
             $(this).datetimepicker("setDate",obj.lastVal);
         }

    }
}
```

calculateTimeDiff() is a function that returns number of milliseconds between start and end date.

**What happens**

If the date selected for start value is after the end value. Then everything acts like supposed. The value is reverted.

But if both start and end value is on the same date and the time is changed so that it exceeds the end value. Then the date value is set to current date and time value isn't reset at all. If the dialog is closed after that, no value is return to the input field.

I've tried console.log(obj) both when you change a date and when you just change the time. 
and found out that obj.lasVal isn't set when just the time is changed. (A bit odd, i think).

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xqo2653k/)**

**Question**

What am i doing wrong or could this be done in some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a better way! You can just constrain both fields so that the start date maximum is the end date and the end date minimum is the start date, using `minDateTime` and `maxDateTime` that take `Date` objects like so:

```
$("#startStamp").datetimepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    timeFormat: "HH:mm",
    showSecond: false,
    controlType: 'select',
    maxDateTime: new Date($('#endStamp').val().replace(/-/g, "/")),
});

$("#endStamp").datetimepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    timeFormat: "HH:mm",
    showSecond: false,
    controlType: 'select',
    minDateTime: new Date($('#startStamp').val().replace(/-/g, "/")),
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/xqo2653k/2/)

**Update**

[image]

[image]

### Update 2

Fix for safari added.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but your fiddle doesn't work. Further more i think this solution only supports the initial value and not a value selected after init by the user (but i could be wrong)

Comment: How is the fiddle not working? I even fixed your fiddle to use actual CDN since github will not work. My solution prevents the user from selecting datetimes outside of logical range.

Comment: it doesn't prevent the user from selecting date/times outside of the range! i can still select 2011-11-10 when end date is 2011-11-09. That shouldn't be possible.

Comment: I don't know what you are seeing, it is not selectable and you cannot type invalid dates in the fields.

Comment: See screenshots and confirm you are at this fiddle address:

[http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/xqo2653k/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/xqo2653k/1/)

Comment: Indeed. But i need cross browser so... :(

Comment: Added fix for safari throwing "invalid date" ;)

Comment: This marks the calendar for the initial value but it is not updated when the date changes... But it is a lot closer then what i got. From this I can redraw the calendar onClose. That should solve it all! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Part of what you were doing wrong, was confusing datetimepicker with datepicker, which have very similar names :). datepicker has onSelect (http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect), but datetimepicker does not (http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/).

Hope this helps